# Java observer / visitor, static visitor

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, static, visitor-pattern

So I have this class which basically handles scene loading. At different point of the program, you notify the visitor with different layer Ids which are supposed to load.

Since I have only one scene handler and logically there can not be more, and the ability to call the loadLayer method and Subscribe method has to be available everywhere, I decided to make it static.

Now my question is: Is this considered to be a bad OOP practice? If so, how should I go about making the class non-static and accessible from everywhere without having to pass it through arguments or in some other way.

Thanks for the help.

`package backend.events;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class LoadLayerHandler
{
    private LoadLayerHandler()
    {

    }
    private final static ArrayList<LoadLayerEvent> subscribers = new ArrayList<LoadLayerEvent>();
    x
    public static final void subscribe(LoadLayerEvent subscriber)
    {
        subscribers.add(subscriber);
    }

    public static final void loadLayer(int layer)
    {
        for(LoadLayerEvent i : subscribers)
        {
            if(i.isBlackList() == false)
            {
                for(int j : i.getLayers())
                {
                    if(j == layer)
                    {
                        i.loadLayer();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        i.unloadLayer();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(int j : i.getLayers())
                {
                    if(j == layer)
                    {
                        i.unloadLayer();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        i.loadLayer();
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: "*Is this considered to be a bad OOP practice?*" - Yes. For example, static methods are hard(er) to test and mock. "*f so, how should I go about making the class non-static and accessible from everywhere without having to pass it through arguments or in some other way.*" - [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: I thought about using the singleton pattern but came to the conclusion that in the end, it will bring to the same point. The instantiation is already restricted using private constructor. How would the singleton change the situation? The point of singleton is is restricting instantiation to a single object. This "global" class is already instantiated and already restricted to instantiation. Care to elaborate?